# Pandas filter dataframe based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with all flagged instruments and other with all blacklisted instruments (Both have a column stating the date each entry were added to the list). id like to select the data from flagged instrument dataframe where their added date is later than the blacklisted dates. My dataframes:

```
>>> flagged[['Isin', 'date_added']]
               Isin  date_added
9854   CNE100001WY7  2023-01-20
18193  CNE100002CY7  2023-01-23
52791  CNE100001WY7  2023-02-05
55151  CNE100002CY7  2023-03-07
56219  CNE100003Q57  2023-03-10

>>> blacklist[['isin', 'Blacklist Date']]
           isin Blacklist Date
0  CNE000001N13     2023-02-09
1  CNE100001WY7     2023-02-09
2  CNE100002CY7     2023-02-09
3  CNE100003Q57     2023-02-09
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how i can get the following output from the flagged dataframe (id like to keep any duplicated values in the output if possible):

```
               Isin  date_added
55151  CNE100002CY7  2023-03-07
56219  CNE100003Q57  2023-03-10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I propose doing a merge and then filter. Assuming each entry for `flagged` has at most one corresponding entry in `blacklist`, otherwise you need to filter to the appropriate `blacklist` entry first. I added some handling for the date as well.

```py
# Sample data table
f_Isin = ['CNE100001WY7', 'CNE100002CY7', 'CNE100001WY7', 'CNE100002CY7', 'CNE100003Q57']
f_date = ['2023-01-20', '2023-01-23', '2023-02-05', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-10']
b_isin = ['CNE000001N13', 'CNE100001WY7', 'CNE100002CY7', 'CNE100003Q57']
b_date = ['2023-02-09', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-09']
flagged = pd.DataFrame({'Isin': f_Isin, 'date_added': f_date})
blacklist = pd.DataFrame({'isin': b_isin, 'Blacklist Date': b_date})

# Format dates
flagged['date_added'] = pd.to_datetime(flagged['date_added'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
flagged['date_added'] = flagged['date_added'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
blacklist['Blacklist Date'] = pd.to_datetime(blacklist['Blacklist Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
blacklist['Blacklist Date'] = blacklist['Blacklist Date'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)

# Merge
merged_df = flagged.merge(blacklist[['isin', 'Blacklist Date']], left_on = 'Isin', right_on = 'isin', how = 'left')
merged_df.drop(columns=['isin'], inplace=True)
# Filter
merged_df[merged_df['date_added'] > merged_df['Blacklist Date']][['Isin', 'date_added']]
```

For cases where there are `NA` values for `Blacklist Date`, you have a couple options. At minimum (plus date processing if needed):

- include in results: `merged_df[(merged_df['Blacklist Date'].isna()) | (merged_df['date_added'] > merged_df['Blacklist Date'])][['Isin', 'date_added']]`
- leave out: `merged_df[(merged_df['Blacklist Date'].notna()) & (merged_df['date_added'] > merged_df['Blacklist Date'])][['Isin', 'date_added']]`

If `blacklist` has more than one entry per instrument, you may choose to use `sort_values(by = 'Blacklist Date')` as you'd like and then use `drop_duplicates`.